# Use data stored in $scope in DevExtreme Widgets

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, devextreme

My code right now is very simple.
In my script.js I have :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['dx']);
myApp.controller("defaultCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("test.json").success(function (response) {
        $scope.data = response;
});

console.log($scope.data);//This shows "undefined"

$(function () {
    $("#gauge").dxCircularGauge({
        rangeContainer: {backgroundColor: 'peachpuff'},
        valueIndicator: {color: 'palegoldenrod'},
        value: 32,
        title: $scope.data[0].title,
        animation: {
            easing: 'linear',
            duration: 750
        }
     })
   });
});
```

Then in my Html file I have a basic AngularJS module.

```
<body ng-controller="defaultCtrl">
    <div id = "gauge">
    </div>
</body>
```

I need to read the settings from the json file, and generate the graph from these settings. However, I am stuck.
Any help would be appreciated. Please don't tell me not to use AngularJS or DevExtreme though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a turning issue. So initially $scope.data is not defined and you try to bind that to your widget.

bind the data inside the success or your the $q promise API

```
$scope.BindWidget = function(data){
  $("#gauge").dxCircularGauge({
        rangeContainer: {backgroundColor: 'peachpuff'},
        valueIndicator: {color: 'palegoldenrod'},
        value: 32,
        title: data[0].title,
        animation: {
            easing: 'linear',
            duration: 750
        }
     })
   });
}

$http.get("test.json").success(function (response) {
       $scope.BindWidget(response);
});
```

Of course you have this issue because you are not using your widget in an angular way. And even though I provided this answer I highly suggest you change your method to the proper way DevExpress recommends.

[Here you  can find more information about how to use your guage control in an angular way so it responds to scope changes and becomes part of your digest cycle](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Howto/Data_Visualization/Basics/Create_a_Widget/?version=14_2#Create_a_Widget_Add_a_Widget_AngularJS_Approach)